# Write to binary file bit by bit c#

Tags: c#

Is it possible in c# like in c++, to write  to file bit by bit.
for exmaple write one bit every iteration of for loop.

```
 void QT (int MINX, int MAXX,int MINY, int MAXY){
    short val = (short)normalizedImg[MINX, MINY];
    for(int x = MINX; x < MAXX; x++){
        for(int y = MINY; y < MAXY; y++){
            if (val != (short)normalizedImg[x,y])
                //Math.Pow(val - (short)normalizedImg[x, y], 2) > Math.Pow(T, 2)
                { 
                //writebit(1);
                QT(MINX,(MINX+MAXX)/2,MINY,(MINY+MAXY)/2);
                QT(MINX,(MINX+MAXX)/2,(MINY+MAXY)/2,MAXY);                
                QT((MINX+MAXX)/2,MAXX,MINY,(MINY+MAXY)/2);
                QT((MINX+MAXX)/2,MAXX,(MINY+MAXY)/2,MAXY); 
                return;
                }
            }

        }
        //Writebit(0)

    }
```

The problem is if I'd do this with the help of string, things get very slow very fast.

Comment: It is possible byte by byte, not bit by bit. If you want to do so, you must accumulate the bits yourself. use bitwise or (|) and shift operations << or >> depending whether you add new bits to the right or left.

Comment: Will try this, thank you

Comment: @RokPotočnik See this answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7067744/633098